# How to run polymer 1 and polymer 2 at the same time

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have started to port my app from p1 to p2 and all elements provided by Google (e.g.  paper elements) work fine. However, I also use some non-google elements which are currently only available for p1. 
To fix some issues I ported some elements to p2 which mostly simply requires changing the bower dependencies to #polymer2-preview. But this is sadly not sufficient for all elements, and some are too complex to port all the code. 
I saw that the polymer-cli provides `variants` that says p1 and p2. Can that somehow be used as a solution?